# AWK Retrieve text after a certain pattern where the 1st and 2nd columns match the values in the 1st and 2nd columns in an input file

Tags: awk

My input file (file1) looks like this:

```
part position col3 col4 info
part1 34 1 1 NAME=Mark;AGE=23;HEIGHT=189
part2 55 1 1 NAME=Alice;AGE=43;HEIGHT=167
part2 19 1 1 NAME=Emily;AGE=16;HEIGHT=164
part3 23 1 1 NAME=Owen;AGE=55;HEIGHT=181
part3 99 1 1 NAME=Rachel;AGE=76;HEIGHT=162
```

I need to retrieve the text after "NAME=" in the info column, but only if the values in the first two columns match another file (file2).

```
part position
part2 55
part3 23
```

Then only the 2nd and 4th rows will be considered and text after "NAME=" in those rows are put into the output file:

```
Alice
Owen
```

I don't need to preserve the order of the original rows, so the following output is equally valid:

```
Owen
Alice
```

My (not very good) attempt:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$5; next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like,

```
awk -F"[ =;]" 'FNR==NR{found[$1" "$2]=$6; next} $1" "$2 in found{print found[$1" "$2]}'
```

**Example**

```
$ awk -F"[ =;]" 'FNR==NR{found[$1" "$2]=$6; next} $1" "$2 in found{print found[$1" "$2]}' file1 file2
Alice
Owen
```

---

**What it does?**

- `-F"[ =;]"` `-F` sets the field separators. Here we set it to space or `=` or `;`. This makes it easier to get the name from the first file without using a `split` function.
- `found[$1" "$2]=$6` This block is run only for file1, here we save the names `$6` in the associative array `found` indexed by `part position`
- `$1" "$2 in found{print found[$1" "$2]}` This is executed for the second file. Checks if the `part position` is found in the array, if yes print the name from the array

Comment: @JamesBrown Are the files in correct order to the awk. In the example above, file1 is the file `NAME` etc

Comment: Excellent answer. However I realized that my files are tab delimited instead of space delimited... I tried substituting the space in the command with tab:
awk -F"[\t=;]" 'FNR==NR{found[$1'\t'$2]=$6; next} $1'\t'$2 in found{print found[$1'\t'$2]}' file1 file2
However there is no output...

Comment: @HollowBastion Try the field separator as `-F"[[:space:]=;]*"`. Also make sure the order of the file, they are very important

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` below would do the same

```
 awk 'NR>1 &&  NR==FNR{found[$1","$2];next}\
      $1","$2 in found{print gensub(/^NAME=([^;]*).*/,"\\1","1",$NF);}' file2 file1
```

**Output**

```
Alice
Owen
```